# Projection onto a set vs. KL minimizer to a set

Tags: probability-distributions, metric-spaces, normal-distribution, projection

I'm interested in the problem "find the closest probability measure in [$KL$-divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) of a set of measures $Q$ to a given measure $p$."

Specifically take $Q$ to be the set of product measures, that is measures where each component is independent: $$Q = \big\{ q(x): q(x) = \prod_{i=1}^d q_i(x_i) : x\in \mathbb{R}^d\big\}.$$

Suppose $p$ is in the [exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family).

How do I find $\arg\min_{q\in Q} KL(q||p)$ for given $p$?

- Is this the same as the projection of $p$ onto $Q$ in some metric?
- Is it possible to just take the marginals $p(x_i)$ and combine them -- getting a product distribution; would this be the $KL$-minimizer? If not, what would this be?

Comment: @TSF Hmm I have a few questions. 1) what's $\mathcal{N}_Q(q^*)$? and 2) $\nabla_q KL(q^*||p) = \int \log (q^*/p) + 1 dx$ ; how did you get the RHS? and if $\mathcal{N}_Q(q^*)$ denotes a set, then what does it mean $(\nabla \phi + \mathcal{N}_Q)^{-1}$?

Comment: @TSF sorry for the confusion. If $\mathcal{N}_Q$ is a set, then how is it also an operator? (Especially one that can be added to $\nabla \phi$?)